# Ionic 2 Dynamic Forms

Tags: forms, multidimensional-array, ionic2, ionic3

I am having issue with Ionic 2 Dynamic forms
the code work for adding additional fields but i am unable to get the dynamic inputs to be posted when i click create button, could someone help me fixing the views?

```
    export class WorkorderAddPage {
         workorder: any = {
        date: '',
        project_name: '',
        item: []

      };
      newArray: any = [];
      constructor() {
        let client = this.navParams.get('client');
        this.workorder.date = new Date().toISOString();
        this.client = client;
        this.newArray = [{
            description: 'Checklist 1',
            start: '',
            end: ''

          },
          {
            description: 'Checklist 2',
            start: '',
            end: ''
          }
        ];

  }
  addItem() {

    this.newArray.push.apply(this.newArray, [{
        description: 'Checklist',
        start: '',
        end: ''
      }
    ]);
  }
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad WorkorderAddPage');
  }

  CreateWorkorder(workorder){
    console.log(workorder);

  }
```

and in the view:

```
 <ion-card>
<ion-list>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label fixed>Project Title</ion-label>
   <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Title of the Project" [(ngModel)]="workorder.project_name"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
   <ion-label fixed>Project Date</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" [(ngModel)]="workorder.date"></ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>

</ion-list>
</ion-card>
<ion-card>
<ion-item>
<h2 (click)="addItem();">Click here to add row</h2>
</ion-item>
</ion-card>

<ion-card *ngFor="let a of newArray, let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
   <ion-row>
          <ion-col col-8>
          <ion-input [(ngModel)]="workorder.item[i][a.description]"  placeholder="Description" type="text"></ion-input>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col col-2>
            <ion-item>
              <ion-datetime displayFormat="HH:mm to" [(ngModel)]="workorder.item[i][a.start]" placeholder="00:00"> </ion-datetime>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col col-2>
            <ion-item>
              <ion-datetime displayFormat="HH:mm" [(ngModel)]="workorder.item[i][a.end]" placeholder="00:00"> </ion-datetime>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>


</ion-card>
<button ion-button color="danger" block (click)="CreateWorkorder(workorder);">Save Workorder</button>
```

Comment: Did my solution worked? Please mee know. I had spent time to create that plunker for you.

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way. [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/RgrF7m?p=preview).

**TS:**

```
workorder: any = {
    date: '',
    project_name: '',
    item: [{
            description: 'Checklist1',
            start: '',
            end: ''

        },
        {
            description: 'Checklist2',
            start: '',
            end: ''
        }
    ]

};
constructor(public navController: NavController) {}
addItem() {
    this.workorder.item.push({
        description: 'Checklist3',
        start: '',
        end: ''
    });
}
CreateWorkorder(workorder) {
    console.log(workorder);

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ion-item>
<h2 (click)="addItem();">Click here to add row</h2>
</ion-item>
<ion-card *ngFor="let a of workorder.item, let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-8>
            <ion-input [(ngModel)]="a.description" placeholder="Description" type="text"></ion-input>
        </ion-col>
.
.
.
.
    </ion-row>
</ion-card>
<button ion-button color="danger" block (click)="CreateWorkorder(workorder);">Save Workorder</button>
```